# Transfer selected rows from excel to google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have an excel spreadsheet with data which cannot be published online entirely. But I have few selected rows which I need to check online. Is there a way to extract those rows from excel and send it to a specific google spreadsheet and append those rows?
For eg I have a column named 'company' and I want only those rows which are for a specific company say 'ABC'. I need to see 'ABC's data online in a google spreadsheet. And the person who will run this script will not have to manually email a separate spreadsheet or so. All this operation should happen automatically by clicking a link or button in excel.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the correct resources to assemble you a working prototype, but these are the steps that I would take if I were in your place.

First, rather than use VBA in Excel, use a full fledged VB.NET application with the Excel Interop COM package.  It's syntax is largely similar to the VBA commands, but to do the transferring to Google docs will be much easier in VB.NET, I think.

You would have to grab the rows that you want with a range object.  Convert that range to an array for ease in handling.

Next, use the [Google Documents List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to create a new spreadsheet, or create one ahead of time and skip this step.

Use the [Google Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) to move the data into your online spreadsheet.

Both Google APIs are REST APIs, so you'll have to use HttpRequest objects in VB.NET. [Here](http://agilecommons.org/posts/238b5dd336) is a great example of how to use them, just change the URLs so they are appropriate for Google.  Google Spreadsheets even offers a [library](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/code.html#client_libraries) that abstracts away many of those steps (second one down on that page).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can send data to Google spreadsheet from Excel, you need google script & VBA code

Open google spreadsheet ==> go tools ===> click script editor ==> paste below code ==> click publish ==> deploy web app ==> select "Anyone,even anonymous"

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


function doPost(e) {
  let data = e.parameter.name
  Logger.log(data)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].appendRow([data])
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data posted")
  
}


paste below code in excel VBA


[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Sub postrequestbymsxml()
    
Dim url As String
    Dim http As Object
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    url = "Write here the url you get while publishing your web app"
    Data = url & "?name=EALLEN"
    http.Open "POST", Data, False
    Debug.Print
    
    http.send ("")
    
End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m01N.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWfzG.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQRgF.png
```